# Android finding X and Y in tween animation

Tags: android, animation, drawable

i have a drawable frame animation and i also implement tween animation on it. In drawable animation my sprites it walking without moving its location. and through tween animation it is moving from x 1% to x 100%.

the code of both animation is as

```
    Animation movement = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.animationball);
    anim.startAnimation(movement);

    anim.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.smurf);
    AnimationDrawable walking = (AnimationDrawable) anim.getBackground();
    walking.start();
```

it is working fine and my animation gives illusion that m sprite walking from left to right.
now i wanted to get  X and Y location of this animated sprite at every pixel of its movement path.

i implements runnable on same activity class and the code of its run() method is as below

```
@SuppressLint("NewApi") @Override
public void run() {

    tv.setText(""+ anim.getX());

}
```

then i start the thread in onCreate method as

```
    Thread t = new Thread(this);
    t.start();
```

in run() method tv is a TextView and i wanted to observe the locations through it. but it always showing 0.0

i am unable to understand it why it is not showing the x locations ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With tween animation or AnimationDrawble and View Animation (Animation class), the animated view's "real" position is not changed even though the view is animated to a different location, for example, you can create a button and animate it to the right side of the screen, but when you click along on the button when it is moving, it will not get depressed, but if you press its initial position (even if the button is not there), the button will get depressed. If you want to also invalidate the view's position, use the new Property Animation, click [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/overview.html) for more detail.